# Vue.js error [Error when rendering root instance] due to async JSON loading

Tags: json, ajax, vue.js, getjson, vuejs2

I am building an app using vue js. In the app I am getting all the data from JSON file and and when I try to load JSON file using jQuery's getJSON() method then it throws an error during rendering the web page

> Error when rendering root instance: vue.js:2229 Uncaught TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'title' of null

My understanding is that I am loading json file in "created method" using jQuery's getJSON() method which is an asynchronous method, so vue js tries to populate json data in my template as soon as it creates the vue instance without waiting for the 100% loading of the json file, so it throws the error "Cannot read property 'title' of null" as I have set the initial value of data model to null. Am I correct? If yes then how can I avoid it ? One way is to use "synchronous ajax request" which is working fine in my case but I think its not a good idea to still use a synchronous request in 2017! as it will frustrate the users in case of long loading duration for JSON file. Guys please help me

Example using jQuery's getJSON() method:

```js
var viewModel = new Vue({
  el: '#templateBody',

  data: {
    jsonData: null
  },
  created: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.fetchJSONData();
  },
  methods: {

    fetchJSONData: function() {

      var self = this;
      $.getJSON("data.json", function(data, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "success") {
          self.jsonData = data;
        } else {
          console.log("JSON data not Loaded.");
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

JSON: {
  "title": "Tilte Text",
  "bodyText": "Body text",
  "_classes": {
    "titleClass": "className"
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="templateBody">
  <h1 id="title" v-if="jsonData.title" :class="jsonData._classes.titleClass">{{ jsonData.title }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `v-if="jsonData"` instead of the `jsonData.title` since jsonData is still undefined at the first moment.

Comment: Could you console.log `data` in true case into the if statement in fetchJSONdata method ?

Comment: @VincentT I have updated my code snippet(earlier I thought it is not relevant), in this case if I replace "jsonData.title" with "jsonData" then it starts throwing the "not defined" error for "jsonData._classes.titleClass" in class binding.

Comment: @BelminBedak When I console.log data inside the fetchJSONdata() method but outside the getJSON() method then it logs the null value.

Comment: I mean to console log data here  `if (status == "success") {
          self.jsonData = data;
          console.log(data);
        } `

Comment: @Aashu.M its the same for the class, vue is processing this tag on load so before the ajax is finished, so that prop is not available at that moment, you can set that class using jquery in the success callback this will give the same result.

Comment: @BelminBedak It logs the JSON object when I log it inside "if" condition.

Comment: @VincentT I dont want to use jQuery because I am trying to create it using  only vue js and I am trying to minimize the use of jQuery but yes what you suggested can be implemented if vue oriented option is not available.

Comment: @Aashu.M then is suggest setting the v-if on the `div` tag and (if you want to minimize the use of jquery you can look a axxios for the ajax part).

Comment: @VincentT yes axios can also be used for ajax requests. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Working Solution:

The problem in the code is the **null initial value of jsonData** in data model. If we replace the null value of 
**jsonData(jsonData: null)** with an **empty object(jsonData: {})** then we do not get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

My understanding is that when we write **v-if="jsonData.title"** then vue considers **jsonData** as a javascript object and tries to find the value of **title** but we have assigned the null value to it that's why it returns the **TypeError**. It is not an issue of aysnc loading of JSON file.

```js
var viewModel = new Vue({
  el: '#templateBody',

  data: {
    jsonData: {}
  },
  created: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.fetchJSONData();
  },
  methods: {

    fetchJSONData: function() {

      var self = this;
      $.getJSON("data.json", function(data, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "success") {
          self.jsonData = data;
        } else {
          console.log("JSON data not Loaded.");
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

JSON: {
  "title": "Tilte Text",
  "bodyText": "Body text",
  "_classes": {
    "titleClass": "className"
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="templateBody">
  <h1 id="title" v-if="jsonData.title" :class="jsonData._classes.titleClass">{{ jsonData.title }}</h1>
</div>
```